# Javascript: Messages written to the console do not remain on screen

Tags: javascript

I have some javascript thats call a function with window.onload and inside of that function is another function that runs when an element is clicked which writes something to the console.

When using a pattern like this the console messages (I'm using Chrome) don't remain in the console window. They appear for a second and disappear. I am new to javascript and curious why this is and a possible when to get console message to remain in the console with this pattern.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function initMenus() {
    var list=document.getElementById("test");
    list.onclick = function() {
        console.log("This text flashes in the console for a second and disappears");
    }
}
window.onload = initMenus;
</script>
</head>
<body>

<a href="" id="test">test</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: when a browser windows in refreshed or move to another link, the console is also refreshed.  Hence you're not seeing it.

Comment: Also, you can change `href=""` to `href="#"` which will keep you on the same page. The same reason @ajm has mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

console messages exist for the lifecycle of a page on their default settings. When you click that link, you navigate away from the page and your console messages are lost.

If you right click on the console, you can select the "Preserve log upon navigation" option. That will save console messages as you navigate between pages.

Comment: Holy crap that was fast. Tested that out and its exactly what I wanted. Also, makes sense to me now why it was disappearing.